# Gem install Fail on Shared VirtualBox Folder

Tags: bundle, virtualbox

There's a Windows Host and an Ubuntu guest using VirtualBox.

We can gem install just fine for individual gems on Ubuntu. When running

```
bundle install --path vendor
```

for an app that is on a shared folder in Ubuntu it fails with.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
/var/www/chef-playground/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:226: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt/chef/embedded/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Activating libxml2 2.8.0 (from /var/www/chef-playground/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ports/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2/2.8.0)...
Extracting libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-linux-gnu/ports/libxslt/1.1.26... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.26 (from /var/www/chef-playground/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ports/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt/1.1.26)...
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... yes
checking for exsltFuncRegister() in -lexslt... yes
checking for xmlHasFeature()... yes
checking for xmlFirstElementChild()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
creating Makefile

Text file busy @ unlink_internal - ./siteconf20140313-27134-167s4eq.rb

Gem files will remain installed in /var/www/chef-playground/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/www/chef-playground/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/nokogiri-1.6.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` succeeds before bundling
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your stack trace has the explanation.

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` succeeds before bundling
```

I ran into the same error while using it on Fedora 20. There is a good explanation of how to overcome it at the [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) site.

I ran the following 2 commands and then the `bundle install` worked:

```
sudo yum install -y rubygem-nokogiri
sudo yum install -y gcc ruby-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of this:

```
Text file busy @ unlink_internal - ./siteconf20140313-27134-167s4eq.rb
```

This is apparently an existing problem with regards to sharedfolders, Virtualbox and Windows hosts. It seems they have been blaming Window's aggressive file handling.

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2282

[Ansible text file busy error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346342/ansible-text-file-busy-error)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52951/gedit-wont-save-a-file-on-a-virtualbox-share-text-file-busy

You can try a workaround by installing the gems somewhere on guest machine instead of inside your sharedfolder i.e. install your gems in your home directory: `bundle install --path ~/vendor`. You might have to reconfigure your `.bundle/config` to make sure you're pointing at the correct directory.